# Где хранить константы в Java/Android?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Хочу писать правильный код, вот задался вопросом. Все-таки где же лучше хранить константы в Java? Сейчас ковыряю коды стандартных приложений Android. Встретил для себя несколько спорных моментов. Хочу задать несколько вопросов:

1. Где же все-таки лучше и правильнее хранить константы, которые используются часто из других классов?
2. Для чего используются `private`/`protected` `interface`? Они, в свою очередь, содержат константы. Вот, например:

> protected interface AlarmsColumns
>   extends AlarmSettingColumns,
>   BaseColumns

А класс, в котором объявлены такие интерфейсы, называется `Contract(ClockContract)`. Сами константы в интерфейсе объявлены как `public static final`. Изначально в коде программы константы использовались так:

> ClockContract.InstancesColumns._ID

Все было хорошо, если использовать из класса в одном пакете, а если класс находится в другом пакете - при попытке доступа IDE писало вполне логичную ошибку, про доступ к `protected`. Также заимплементить можно, только если находишься в одном пакете. 
Хотя, почитав официальные доки и интернет, хранение констант в интерфейсе считается вроде антипаттерном.

Объясните, пожалуйста, для чего было так сделано? Как работают `protected`/`private` `interface` и где же всё-таки лучше хранить константы?
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 6):

> Где же все-таки лучше и правильнее хранить константы, которые используются часто из других классов?

В `public static final` полях класса или в `public Enum`'ах (как, например, [тут](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.java) и [тут](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.java)).

> Для чего используются private/protected интерфейсы. Они, в свою очередь, содержат константы ...
>   для чего было так сделано

Сделано это скорее всего, чтобы сгруппировать константы и ограничить к ним доступ. Не все константы должны быть доступны отовсюду, некоторые нужны только в классе, некоторые только в пакете и наследниках.

> как работают protected/private intrfaces

Возьмём такую иерархию классов:

```
    |\ - Main.java
    | | - foo
    | |\
    | | | - A.java
    | | | - B.Jjava
    | | | - C.java
    | |
    | | - bar
    | |\
    | | | - D.java
```

И код:

```
// foo/A.java
package foo;

public class A {
    public static interface PublicInnerInterface {
        public static final int A_PUBLIC_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST = 0;
    }
    protected static interface ProtectedInnerInterface {
        public static final int A_PROTECTED_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST = 1;
    }
    private static interface PrivateInnerInterface {
        public static final int A_PRIVATE_INTERFACE_CONST = 2;
    }
    protected static class InnerClass {
        protected static final int A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST = 3;
    }
    protected static final int A_CONST =
            PrivateInnerInterface.A_PRIVATE_INTERFACE_CONST;
}

// foo/B.java
package foo;

public class B {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("B -> A_PROTECTED_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST: " 
                + A.ProtectedInnerInterface.A_PROTECTED_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST);
        System.out.println("B -> A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST: " 
                + A.InnerClass.A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST);
        System.out.println("B -> A_CONST: " 
                + A.A_CONST);
    }
}

// foo/C.java
package foo;

public class C extends A {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("C -> A_PROTECTED_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST: " 
                + ProtectedInnerInterface.A_PROTECTED_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST);
        System.out.println("C -> A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST: " 
                + InnerClass.A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST);
        System.out.println("C -> A_CONST: " 
                + A_CONST);
    }
}

// bar/D.java
package bar;

import foo.A;

public class D extends A {
    protected static class InnerClass extends A.InnerClass {
        public static final int A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST = 
                A.InnerClass.A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST + 10;
    }
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("D -> A_PROTECTED_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST: " 
                + ProtectedInnerInterface.A_PROTECTED_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST);
        System.out.println("D -> A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST: " 
                + InnerClass.A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST);
        System.out.println("D -> A_CONST: " 
                + A_CONST);
    }
}

// Main.java
import bar.D;
import foo.A;
import foo.B;
import foo.C;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main -> A_PUBLIC_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST: "
                + A.PublicInnerInterface.A_PUBLIC_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST);

        B b = new B();
        b.test();

        C c = new C();
        c.test();

        D d = new D();
        d.test();
    }
}
```

- `A_PUBLIC_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST` доступна везде
- `A_PROTECTED_INNER_INTERFACE_CONST` доступна классам, лежащим в том же пакете и классам-наследникам (даже из других пакетов). У наследников необязательно писать `A.` для доступа к внутренним классам/интерфейсам и статическим полям.
- `A_PRIVATE_INTERFACE_CONST` доступна только внутри класса A (в том числе, во внутренних class/interface/enum)
- `A_PROTECTED_INNER_CLASS_CONST` доступна классам, лежащим в том же пакете. Эта protected-константа недоступна напрямую наследникам, лежащим в других пакетах. Однако, сам защищённый класс доступен всем наследникам и можно отнаследоваться от него, чтобы получить значение этой константы (см. класс `D`). Имя можно задать другое (статические члены всё равно не наследуются), а можно и перезаписать с тем же именем.
- `A_CONST` доступна классам, лежащим в том же пакете и классам-наследникам (даже из других пакетов).

Вообще, нет какого-то общего чёткого соглашения, всё зависит от смысла константы.

- Где хранить:

  - *В самом классе* - если константа непосредственно связана с классом
  - *Во вложенном class/interface/enum* - если несколько констант можно сгруппировать по-смыслу, но они всё-равно тесно связаны с самим классом
  - *В отдельном class/interface/enum* - если несколько констант можно сгруппировать, но они имеют смысл вне какого-либо класса
- Какой поставить доступ:

  - *public* - если константа широко используется другими классами
  - *protected* - если константа используется внутри пакета или имеет смысл разрешить использовать её в классах-наследниках, ограничив доступ всем остальным
  - *private* - если константа используется только внутри класса